# Airline ticket dispute

Tags: legal, airline

If I can't resolve a ticket refund issue (ticket was not honored because of a computer thing) with the airline or PayPal (more than 45 days) who else can help me with the dispute? FAA or small claims court or anyone else?

I purchased a Qatar Airways ticket to Pakistan. I then changed the dates 2 weeks prior to departure and paid the change of ticket fee. I received a confirmation. I called the service center ahead of time to confirm that the reservation was changed and received affirmation. On return from Pakistan, they the agent said that my reservation was not changed and I had to purchase a new return ticket. Now when I check with the airline they say that the change was not done as the credit card did not accept the charge for the change fee. And that an email had been sent 2 weeks prior to my departure. They will not accept my argument that their customer service confirmed the change on the day of travel.
If I cannot resolve this with the airline who can help me resolve this? Can I take to a court or FAA or some other customer agency?

Comment: How did you pay for the original tickets? Credit card or paypal? How did you pay for the change fee? Do you have proof that you paid for both? Where were you flying from?

Comment: Why didn't the credit card accept the charge for the change fee? I'd be talking to the credit card company, too, if they erred.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think FAA will care about tickets between Qatar and Pakistan. I'm pretty sure it was not an American airline, FAA is part of the US government and has no jurisdiction neither in Qatar nor in Pakistan.

Small claims court (or equivalent) in the country where the selling agency/airline is based is the venue.

Comment: It's quite possible that he was flying between the U.S. and Pakistan, though I'm not sure if that would change anything. Qatar Airways may operate in the U.S. but aren't a U.S. airline.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I doubt they have a direct route from the US to Pakistan. The leg from Qatar to Pakistan has nothing to do with FAA